# Passing parameters to mapper function in a pipeline

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How would I pass parameters to my defined `mapper` function in a mapreduce `mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline`?

I am using a `DatastoreInputReader` as input source. Usually, I only need a simple mapper function:

```
def mapper(model_entity_instance):
  """ my mapper function """
```

But this time I would need something like:

```
def mapper(model_entity_instance, params_dict):
  """ my mapper function """
```

How do I achieve this through the standard `mapreduce` package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way:

```
from mapreduce import context

def mapper(model_entity_instance, params_dict):
  """ my mapper function """
  ctx=context.get()
  mapper_params=ctx.mapreduce_spec.mapper.params
```